# How to set a card's state as learning?

Tags: anki

I have an Anki deck, called ASL-Browser, which I downloaded from the Anki shared decks. I have the deck options set so that it doesn't show *any* new cards; instead, when I learn new words, I go into the browser, look for the note, and then Ctrl-Shift-D to set its due date to 0.

However, this puts the cards into the "Review" queue, and not the "New" queue.I was wondering if there was a way to add cards to the "New" queue rather than straight to the "Review" queue at 0 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

If you only want to introduce certain cards of this deck, the recommended approach is to suspend all of the deck's cards, and then manually unsuspend the ones you want to study.